# Optimize performances of text replacement with dictionary

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace, while-loop, tree

I'm developing an extension for Firefox.

To summarize let's say it's a spell checker applied to a page with a lot of mistakes.

**But it's very slow because there are too many steps.**

**(1)** I create a TreeWalker that filters only not-empty text nodes

```
var tree = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
  acceptNode: function(node) {
    if (node.parentNode.nodeName !== "SCRIPT" && node.nodeValue.trim().length > 0) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

**(2)** A while loop skims the TreeWalker

**(3)** In this while loop, a for loop skims the dictionary (which is quite big) with a complex `RegEx`

```
const dico = [
  ['suffix1','suffix2','correction'],
  ['','',''],
  ['','',''],
  // a lot of lines
];
```

**(4)** Text is replaced

```
dl = dico.length;

function skim(){
  while (tree.nextNode()) {
    for (var i=0; i < dl ; i++) {
      var r1 = new RegExp("([a-zÀ-ÖÙ-öù-üœŒ]+)?(" + dico[i][0] + ")[-/·∙.•](" + dico[i][1] + ")[-/·∙.•]?(s)?(?![a-z])", "gi");
      tree.currentNode.nodeValue = tree.currentNode.nodeValue.replace(r1, dico[i][3]);
    }
  }
}
```

Plus, I'd like to use an other function that highlights the spelling mistakes, so that means adding a lot of Element Nodes between Text Nodes.

How can I optimize that please ?  :)

For the moment, the only solution I found is to simplify the dictionary but I I came to an end with this. And replace the `TreeWalker` by equivalents but it's faster.

Thanks !

Comment: You could asynchronously iterate with the tree walker, so that you won't block the UI. You are still running a lot of complicated regexes against all of the texts. Can't you create one regex?

Comment: What do you mean by asynchronously ? I'm not very familiar with asynchronous functions. No, cannot create one RegEx. The dictionary is mandatory :/

Comment: I basically mean `(function next() { /* do stuff */ setTimeout(next); })();` But can't you turn the dictionary into *one* regex?

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't slow down the browser ? But the user will see the text being changed one after the other ? I suppose I have to replace the `while` loop with the `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With that it will take even longer, but it'll fix the lag. (And you could try memoizing the regexes as patch: Create an array of regexes once, then run them against all the texts)

Comment: Oh ok, so if I understand well, I replace my dictionary with a series of full RegExes. Last question, what setTimeout time do you think I should use ? Maybe I should calculate the dictionary skim time for 1 word and set a bit more of this value for the setTimeout? Thanks for your answers by the way!

Comment: Would you be able to implement a string search algorithms (anyone one of these here that makese sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) and get indices of starting positions to plreace and create a map of "index: correction") and then replace the node with a new "fragment" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Comment: I'd use 0. The browser will shedule that in a way that it does not block the UI.

Comment: @SungM.Kim Thanks a lot, looks complex but very interresting ! I'll try at once.

Comment: @JonasWilms Wow, clever browsers, gonna be simple this time :) thx again

Comment: As @JonasWilms pointed out, don't forget to cache the Regular Expressions instead of re-initializing them in each while iteration. I was thinking, something along these lines: https://jsfiddle.net/q0b27ems/

Comment: @KostasX Cooool that's great ! I'll come back after some tries :)

Comment: @JonasWilms @KostasX I did this [see my own aswer] with KostasX's solution (which is very fast !) however the `setTimeout` solution is fast but missing some nodes. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an update with KostasX's and Jonas Wilms' propositions.

Thats much faster because it memoizes the regexes, so that they don't have to be recreated on every node.

Additionally it iterates asynchronously, to not block the UI.

```
function skim() {
  dicomap.map((replace_entry)=>{
    tree.currentNode.nodeValue = tree.currentNode.nodeValue.replace(replace_entry[0],replace_entry[mode]);
  });

  if(tree.nextNode()) setTimeout(skim);
}
skim();
```

Comment: You call `tree.nextNode()` twice in each loop. And there is no sense in clearing the timeout, just don't start a new one.

Comment: You mean `if (!tree.nextNode())` is asking the TreeWalker to go to the next node already ? If I don't clear the timeout, how it is suppose to know we reached the last node to stop looping ? Plus it's strange, it works perfectly fine in local but not within the Firefox extension

Comment: This looks like a race condition. Also, are you sure you are not getting yourself into an infinite loop? Why don't you try to decouple your skim function from the tree loop? Maybe this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/erdnw7jy/1/

In your case, I would try to work with async/await/promises. Here's some sample code that might help: https://jsfiddle.net/rqgh5L48/

Comment: First solution works great, don't think the second one is mandatory though. Thx thx thx